# How to find out if a user's facebook friend has joined my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

A lot of apps have this features where you get a notification when your facebook friend joins the app. I am wondering if this is via some special API? If not, how would I go about doing this?

I have thought about doing it like this: When a user signs up via facebook, I record their facebook ID and using graph API get all their facebook friends. Then when another user signs up via facebook, I check if any of the previous use have the new's user's fb id in their friends list, if so, I send a notification.

I am wondering if this is the way to do it or if there's some other way/API that is the norm. The downside to my way is that the friends list is not updated after they sign up and also I have to keep list of their friends in my database..
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of fetching the users friends and comparing them to the users in your database, simply use this API call:

```
/{user_id}/friends?fields=installed
```

Of course you can add [other fields](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) to this list to get more data of the friends.

Comment: WOW. Exactly what I was looking for! You have no idea how happy I am right now! Thank you.

Comment: There is a bug with this currently. If the user does not allow all permissions you ask for (e.g. if they skip `publish_stream`), they will not show up as "installed" even though they have installed the app. Bug report here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/482690475142038?browse=external_tasks_search_results_51db313d012149873154853

Comment: the bug mentioned by @andrewtweber is now marked as resolved: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/178979062276800

Comment: Hi how do we know which app is the user talking about here?

Comment: @vini what exactly do you mean? The token you're making the request with is app-specific and therefore will be in the context of this app.